# Why importing QGIS rasters into GRASS Mapset is not working

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I am using GQGIS 3.30. I enabled GRASS and Processing Plugins, and pointed them to the right directory. I created a new mapset and location. Then I used the GRASS toolbox "Import  raster into GRASS from QGIS view" tool from the GRASS toolbar to import the data into GRASS. It runs fine. But then when I click on View Output, it adds it to the legend, but it has a little red warning icon and it says "Unavailable Layer". How do I get it to work?
I can open the layer in GRASS GUI fine, but there the zoom doesn't work. Not sure if it's related.